# Laravel Api method

Tags: laravel

Hello I am trying to create my venues registration values from Laravel API (POST URL) and I am doing right when I check with `postman` and it shows me the success values and when I give the same routes controllers and whatever I need I give to the mobile app developer and when he tried to run the same thing which is obviously working fine it does not work there it shows

`CLIENT PROTOCOL EXCEPTION` I does not understand what to do 
Any help will highly appreciated

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: client protocol exception
```

Comment: Are you able to post some of the code from your route as well as the full error you are getting?

Comment: Also, what is your mobile client, iOS, application? Why do you think it's error on back-end side and not front-end side?

Comment: Also, are your sure your client is accessing the application through HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the guzzle http package, it is bundled with the `CLientException` error class which is an extension of the laravel  `RuntimeException`. This is caused by a a wrong url fed into the guzzle http library.
for instance a 
    $http = new guzzleclient;

```
        $response = $http->post('localhost/stack/overflow', [
            'form_params' => [
                "params" => "params"


            ],
        ]);
```

make sure you change the 'localhost/stack/overflow' url to your current server url, else it will throw errors.

I hope this helps.. Cheers